# How to display the result of my php in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, pdo

I want to do is display the result of my count.php in my index page. My plan is to auto count the number of rows of user_code and display the result in the index page everytime the page is visited or viewed.

My problem is that the ajax script doesnt recieve the result of count.php to display it in count inputbox on index page.

index page:

```
<input type="text" value="1" name="countValue" id="countValue" style="width: 12px;" /><br />
Count: <input type="text" name="count" id="count" readonly="readonly" /><br /><br /><br />

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var countTimer = setInterval(
        function ()
        {
        codeValue();        
        }, 500);



var  $count = $('#count');

function codeValue(){
        $.ajax({
        url:"count.php",
        type:"GET",
        data: { term : $('#countValue').val() },
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function(result) {

         $("#count").val(result.user_code);

        }

    });

};

});      
</script>
```

count.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "test";

$dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);
$dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo $_GET['term'];

if (isset($_GET['term'])) {

$q = $_GET['term'];

$sql = "SELECT user_code FROM students";
$query = $dbc->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$num_rows = $query->rowCount(); 

echo json_encode(array('user_code'=>$num_rows)); 

}

?>
```

Comment: What error message you are getting ?

Comment: please check error in console

Comment: what is the response of your count.php page ??

Comment: remove this line too **var  $count = $('#count');**

Comment: @sharif other than being unused, that will not be contributing to OP's problem

Comment: try to use `console.log(result)` in your success function.and check what you get.

Comment: i try your code and it works! on my pc...check your query if there is data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem

```
echo $_GET['term'];
```

This breaks the expected JSON format that your script is meant to produce. Also, you aren't even using any request parameters so I don't know why you'd even bother.

Here's your PHP, all cleaned up

```
<?php

try {
    $dbc = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'root', '',
        [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

    $stmt = $dbc->query('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM students');

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(['user_code' => $stmt->fetchColumn()];
} catch (Exception $e) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I'd also suggest adding an `error` callback to your `$.ajax` options to handle HTTP errors.

Comment: oh the problem is the echo $_GET['term'] i forgot to remove it becauase i was trying to test if the count.php receive the data.

Answer (score 0):

i try your code and it works for my table i have (4) records! check your query if there is data

make sure you have jquery file in your header. I did not change anything your html file. I just create my own query on my table. then okay.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a div in indexfile and id of that div is provided in ajax file,so as to populate data form count.php in that div.

Here i will give you a similar type of example, Try it by making your related changes

index.php

```
<div id="content">                        
</div>                        
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $.ajax({
      url: 'count.php',
      success: function(data) {
        $('#content').html(data);
      }
    });
<script>
```

count.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "test";
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT user_code FROM students");
?>
<table>//this table will be loaded in div
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['user_code']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

You can also add autorefresh ajax script which will only reload only particular div after specific time interval(1 sec in below code) without reloading whole page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#content').load('count.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

</script>
```